# get hyperparameters during hyperparamter tuning cloud ml-engine

Tags: google-cloud-ml, hyperparameters

I run a hyperparameter tuning job on cloud ml-engine. Only when a trial is concluded I can get the values of hyperparameters in `Job details` and in `Training output`.

I wonder if there is a way to get the values of hyperparameters while the trial is running.

**Edit:** I think it's a better idea to dump the hyperparameters during training programmatically using `tf.gfile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

currently CloudML Engine doesn't expose the `training output` until finishing all trials.

If you hope to learn the detailed hyperparameters for each trial, you should be able to find it from stackdriver logs. There is a log entry that records the command to invoke your trainer code for each trial: `Running command: python -m trainer.task <params>`